# Recursive Reverse List

Tags: c++, pseudocode

I need to write an algorithm called reverseNodes that takes a RefToNode as a parameter and recuriveley reverses the list the header i came up with was

Algorithm reverse (rList)

reverves elementsin a list

Pre: rList :: a referance to a list to be reversed

Post: elements in rList are reversed

if ( rList !=NULL)
reverseNodes (rList -> head)
return

I need to find a way to write this is psuedocode and find the time complexity

Comment: If I was clever, I would search the internet for "c++ reverse linked list example".  But, I guess today is not a day to be clever.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is easier to create some un-formal algorithm gibberish, if you start
with the idea expressed clearly. Then, obfuscate and verbalize until you have something, your professor will happily accept.

So, lets start with our general idea of the algorithm:

```
let rec fold folder acc l = 
    match l with
    | [] -> acc
    | x::xs -> fold folder (folder acc x) xs

let prepend l e = e :: l

let revlist l = fold prepend [] l
```

...and start to verbalize:

1. let result = empty list
2. let l = the list we want to reverse
3. if l is the empty list, goto 7
4. let head = l.front, l = l.pop_front()
5. result.push_front head
6. goto 3
7. l = result

The steps 3..6 can be easily expressed as a recursive function:

```
void loop(list& l, list& result)
{
    if( l.is_empty()) return;
    auto head = l.front();
    l.pop_front();
    result.push_front(head);
    loop(l,result);
}
```

As we want to create the illusion of in-place.reversal, our reverse_list function is

```
void reverse_list( list& l )
{
    list result;
    loop( l, result);
    l = result;
}
```

**Alternate solution**

We can also do it in another way:

```
let rec revlist1 l =
    match l with
    | [] -> l
    | x::xs -> (revlist1 xs) @ [x]
```

This basically states, that the reversed list is the front element of the original list appended to the reverse of the rest.

Translating the algorithm to gibberish form yields:

```
Node* reverse_list1( Node* list )
{
    if( list == NULL) return NULL; // reverse of empty list is empty list.
    if( list->next == NULL ) // last element in list?
        return list; // the reverse of a list with 1 element is the same.
    else
    {
        Node* head = list;
        Node* tail = list->next;
        head->next = NULL;
        Node* end_of_reverse_tail = tail; // the first will be the last...
        Node * result = reverse_list1(tail);
        end_of_reverse_tail->next = head;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Note, that this is not a tail recursive solution.

Comment: Well explained @BitTickler ! I upvoted this obvious propaganda for functional languages

Comment: Not sure how long those links last but.... https://ideone.com/d6VZYQ shows the alternate solution in action.